# (Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error"

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire, using with HTTP cause no problem but I got below when I changed protocol HTTP to HTTPS

> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error" 
>   UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes =
>   0x100201bb5d5efc420000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=100,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1})

**Cod I have tried:**

```
public init(){}
static let shared = HTTPRequest()

func Service(method:String,path:String,
             parameters:[String:String]? = nil,
             requestObj:Any? = nil,
             actionListener:ActionListener){

    actionListener.start()
    var _url = URLComponents(string: BaseURL + path)

    if parameters != nil{
        var queryItems = [URLQueryItem]()
        for parameter in parameters!{
            let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: parameter.key, value: parameter.value)
            queryItems.append(queryItem)
        }
        _url?.queryItems = queryItems
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: (_url?.url)!)

    request.httpMethod = method
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    if MobileConstants.AccessToken != nil{
         request.setValue(MobileConstants.AccessToken, forHTTPHeaderField:"Authorization")
        request.setValue(MobileConstants.LoginResponse.user.userName, forHTTPHeaderField: "UserName")
    }
    request.setValue("iOS", forHTTPHeaderField: "ClientToken")
    request.setValue("en-US", forHTTPHeaderField: "Language")
    if(requestObj != nil){
    let json = JSONSerializer.toJson(requestObj!)
    request.httpBody = json.data(using: .utf8)
    }

    Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON {
        response in
        if(response.result.isSuccess){
            actionListener.success(from: path, data: response.result.value!)
        }else{
            actionListener.fail()
            print(response.error)
            print(response.result.error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a fundamental solution, I solved it with...

Add the following to apache's httpd.conf

```
Header unset Upgrade
```

and restart

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem then I figured it out the problem was HTTP body, I set my HTTP body to nil when HTTP method is GET